# Data Mappers calling each other in Domain Driven Design pattern

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, datamapper

In my project I am using a Domain Driven Design Pattern. I have various data mappers that I use for persisting my model objects. Some of my models contain other models as attributes (e.g., model class Book contains an array of model classes Person as authors).

```
Book
  |->string title
  |->Person[] authors
```

Each model has a corresponding mapper (e.g. Book_Mapper, Perspon_Mapper).

Is it ok for one mapper to make a call to another mapper when persisting a model object:

E.g., when persisting a Book object, I call

```
Book_Mapper::Save(Book)
```

which calls

```
Person::Mapper(Person)
```

for each author of the book?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a DDD perspective, to address the question regarding [data mappers](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) it is important to first distill your model a bit and determine your [aggregates](http://devlicio.us/blogs/casey/archive/2009/02/16/ddd-aggregates-and-aggregate-roots.aspx), entities and value objects.

Suppose that `Book` is an aggregate and a `Person` is a value object. In that case, there is no need to create a separate mapper for `Person` because it is always persisted as part of the `Book` aggregate and so the mapper for books should handle mapping the person as well. In fact, creating a separate mapper for person may be confusing.

If however `Person` is also an aggregate, then it would be best to have `Book` reference the author by ID alone. In this case, there is no need to call the person mapper when persisting a book.

Comment: To add to what eulerfx is saying here: if `Person` is an aggregate you may actually be after an `Author` value object to contain the list of authors in your `Book` aggregate.  Typically a list of person IDs would suffice but you may need more information on the VO or even denormalize some data such as the author name for some lightweight CQRS / Query / Reporting / Read Model stuff.

Comment: Ok, so if I can have a Person who can be an author of several books, the way to go would be to merely store an id of the person in an attribute of a Book and call Book and Persion Mappers when a new book has to be persisted, right?

Comment: @silentser: When a new book is being persisted you shouldn't need to call a person mapper since you're only storing the ID. When you query however, you can create a dedicated [read-model](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/25/read-models-as-a-tactical-pattern-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/) to join in all required data.

Comment: Thank you! That what I have done. My scenario is more complex than Books and Authors, but it serves its purpose as an example, so I will continue with it. I am using Book::getAuthors() getter with lazy load that returns me all the authors of the book. There is, however, no Book::setAuthor(Person) setter, just Book::setAuthorId(int).

Comment: @silentser Omg, are you using static methods in the Domain to deal with persistence?

Comment: @MikeSQ No, they are not static - maybe the notation is not very fortunate :)